# Why am I getting an error trying to create a pandas dataframe with just tickers so that I can manipulate it in the future using finviz?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

This is the code I have with the help of a previous commenter, who suggested adding lines 7 and 8:

```
from pyfinviz.screener import Screener
import pandas as pd
options = [Screener.IndustryOption.STOCKS_ONLY_EX_FUNDS, 
Screener.AnalystRecomOption.STRONG_BUY_1]
screener = Screener(filter_options=options, view_option=Screener.ViewOption.VALUATION,
                    pages=[x for x in range(1, 4)])
t_list = [df['Tickers'] for df in screener.data_frames]    
tickers_df = pd.concat(t_list).reset_index(drop=True)    
print(tickers_df)
```

But now I get this error:

```
t_list = [df['Tickers'] for df in screener.data_frames]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are getting is the error is due to `screener.data_frames` as it is returning an int rather than a list of DataFrames.

The Screener class in `pyfinviz.screener` returns the number of data frames collected rather than the data frames themselves.
The `get_data_frames` method can be used to access the data frames.

For example:

```
from pyfinviz.screener import Screener
import pandas as pd

options = [Screener.IndustryOption.STOCKS_ONLY_EX_FUNDS, Screener.AnalystRecomOption.STRONG_BUY_1]
screener = Screener(filter_options=options, view_option=Screener.ViewOption.VALUATION, pages=[x for x in range(1, 4)])

data_frames = screener.get_data_frames()
tickers_df = pd.concat([df['Tickers'] for df in data_frames]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(tickers_df)
```